# Finding the maximum and minum value of a Pandas Multi index Pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table as shown below.I need to find the maximum and minimum value present in the column
"Chip_Current[uAmp]".could you please tell me how to approach this?

Please see my code below

```
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import plotly 
import cufflinks as cf
#Enabling the offline mode for interactive plotting locally
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
%matplotlib inline
init_notebook_mode()

df = pd.read_csv("Chip_Current_pdm_dis_Corners_2p0_A.txt",delim_whitespace=True)
F_16MHz=LP = df[(df['Frequency[MHz]'] == 1.6)]
F_16MHz_PVT=pd.pivot_table(F_16MHz, index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]','Frequency[MHz]'],values = 'Chip_Current[uAmp]')
F_16MHz_PVT['SPEC_MAX[uA]']=710
F_16MHz_PVT
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the code which makes this dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.min()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) and [`.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) functions, as follows:

```
F_16MHz_PVT['Chip_Current[uAmp]'].min()
F_16MHz_PVT['Chip_Current[uAmp]'].max()
```